# Access to DOM in <object> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, object

I have this code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GhKNQ/2/).

HTML:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.w3.org/" style="width:100%; height:100%;position: absolute;bottom: 0;"></object>
```

JS:

```
console.log($('object').find('*').length);
```

In  tag there is strange **#document** tag and I can't find any tag in there Console says, that there are zero elements.

How can I read from DOM in `<object>`? What is #document in `<object>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `<object>` elements to load HTML documents. Use `<iframe>`s instead - the support and APIs are better.

Then you can use

```
var frame_contents = $('iframe').contents(); 
console.log($(frame_contents).find("*").length);
```

… subject to the usual cross origin security restrictions if you load a document from a different origin.